# Null exception - ctor not called in WPF

Tags: wpf

Visual Studio 2015 Debug

In the XAML get an error on

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Poker"
```

The error is XMLParseException, and then SystemArgumentNullException in System.Core.DLL

The ctor of `Poker.MainWindow` is never called
App.xaml.cs is called but it does nothing
The next step is the error on xmlns:local
This is a app I have been working of for a couple weeks and no problems

Clean, rebuild shows no errors
Run Code Analysis finds no errors
I think there is something about runtime parsing that is breaking it.

if I remove xmlns:local I can add it back by browsing to Poker

Other applications run just fine on this PC
The PC did not crash

Someone asked for code

```
<Window x:Class="Poker.MainWindow"      
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Poker"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"          
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
    Title="No Limit Holdem Poker 6 Player Sit And Go (SNG) - Beat the Bots" Height="600" Width="650">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bvc" />
    <local:BackGroundConverter x:Key="backGroundConverter"/>
    <local:BackGroundConverterCard x:Key="backGroundConverterCard"/>
    <local:BackGroundConverterSuit x:Key="backGroundConverterSuite"/>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="StdMargin">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="StdMarginPlus">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="24,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    </Style>
    <Color x:Key="ColorMyLighLightGray">#EDEDED</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushMyLightLightGrey"  Color="{StaticResource ColorMyLighLightGray}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10,0,2,0">
</Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
//using System.Threading;

namespace Poker
{

    public enum enumSuite : byte { spade = 0, club = 1, heart = 3, diamond = 4, none = 5 };
    public enum enumRank : byte { one = 1, two = 2, three = 3, four = 4, five = 5, six = 6, seven = 7, eight = 8, nine = 9, ten = 10, jack = 11, queen = 12, king = 13, ace = 14 };
    public enum enumHand : byte { high = 0, onePair = 1, twoPair = 2, trip = 3, straight = 4, flush = 5, boat = 6, quad = 7, strtFlush = 8 };
    public enum enumHandDraw : byte { onePair = 1, twoPairTrips = 2, straight = 4, flush = 5, boat = 6, quad = 7, strtFlush = 8 };
    public enum enumPlayerType : byte { callSn = 0, rock = 1, GTO = 2 };

    // 0 nothing
    // 1 pair
    // 2 pair
    // 3 trips
    // 4 straight 
    // 5 flush
    // 6 boat
    // 7 four of a kind 
    // 8 straight flush 

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ctor");  // does not get called
            //LoopCount();
            ProcessShuffle();
            EveryOneBet(0, true);
            before = false;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: @Clemens MainWindow has a ctor and it is not called

Comment: Unclear what I am asking?  Nothing else to give.  That is the line with error and that is the error message.  What else do you need?

Comment: Working example (MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.cs) where the problem is reproduced would be helpful to understand the root cause of the problem.

Comment: In `MainWindow()`, i would move any custom code after `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: @jstreet How would that address the ctor not called at all?  If I put it first it is still not called.   The purpose of those other calls are to have values for when  InitializeComponent(); is called.

Comment: If either `ProcessShuffle()` or `EveryoneBet()` enters an infinite loop or never end for whatever reason, it could give the "impression" that the constructor was never called because it couldn't finish properly. I would place those function calls in the `Loaded` event handler, not in the constructor.

Comment: @jstreet  For the third time the ctor is NOT called at all.   Debug.WriteLine("ctor"); is not called.  I put a break point on that line and it does not get there.   None of those lines are are called.  Commenting them out changes nothing.

Comment: I tried your XAML and code and it works just fine. "ctor" gets printed to the output window in Visual Studio. The only difference is that  my `ProcessShuffle()` and `EveryoneBet()` are empty in my case.

Comment: @jstreet Thanks.  What I post was clearly just a piece.  But even if I empty the grid to be like what I posted I get the error.  I am going to just try a fresh project and see if I can copy paste.

Comment: @jstreet You led me to the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not post all the code

Actually it was in the code behind

I had

```
namespace 
{
    MainWindow
    {
    }
    public class 
    {
    }
}
```

And I moved a class into main window in order to access a static variable
And that broke things badly with no compiler errors

```
namespace 
{
    MainWindow
    {
        public class 
        {
        }
    }
}
```